# How to run a Java app which uses npm on AWS Lambda

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda written in Spring Boot. The Spring Boot code makes use of a `Process` to execute a `npm` command.

This is perfectly fine when running on a server as I can globally install npm packages.

What's the best way to get this working in a lambda?

I toyed around with https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-container-image-converter attempting to create a custom runtime environment which has both Java and the npm package I need. However I wasn't able to get very far due to lack of understanding. I'm even sure if this is the right tool to be using.

So, how can I run both a Java application and execute a npm command in a single lambda?

Comment: Dumb question, but why don’t you split the two runtimes into separate lambda functions?

Comment: I think I mention in the answer below; The Java app does some pre-processing on files, I then need to consume those files with a NodeJs package. Splitting to two Lambdas means I'd need to store the files somewhere from the Java processing, then retrieve them for the NodeJs processing, and send back to Java for further processing. I don't really want to push data back and forth from S3 buckets etc.

Comment: Further, github.com/zeit/pkg was trivial to use and worked perfectly. I've just bundled the NodeJs package with my Jar and all is well in the world. I know its not the must elegant solution, but works for this edge-case of mine.

Comment: ah makes sense! Glad you found a solution that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are only two options:

- Use a AWS Layers with npm binary. As you mentioned you can use a custom runtime or add a new layer to your existing lambda function.
- Invoke another lambda function with nodejs runtime synchronously and capture the response. Check java SDK method for [Invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) endpoint

Depending on your particular problem, there also a 3rd option to convert your nodejs library into a executable binary using [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) or a similar library

Comment: Yeah I'd considered your second point, however that just becomes fiddly as the nodejs depends on files created by the java process, so would mean sending them to S3 then retrieving them again

Comment: Nexe looks like it might solve the problem. I did look around for something to do that, but was missing the right keywords I guess.

Comment: Yeah I had a partial success with nexe you can also check https://github.com/zeit/pkg